# Unexpected ESC behavior upon propeller contamination

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, quad-copter

**Background:**
I am investigating propeller behavior upon contamination.
For that i built a test rig with one DJI E800 brushless motor, E620s ESC (sensorless) and standard prop. I am giving the ESC a constant input signal pulse width and monitoring rotational speed, consumed power and thrust.
I have a continuous increase of contamination over time.

**Issue:**
Apart from decreasing thrust I noticed that with heavy propeller contamination the motor rotaional speed is reduced (probably due to larger drag/mass of the propeller) and the consumed power increases (**Edit:** increased Amperage at same Voltage).

**Question:**
I cannot wrap my head around this.
**Edit:** An increase of load (drag increase) should lead to a lagging of the rotor, which again leads to an increase of amperage  and finally to an increase of torque and a syncing of the rotor, thus keeping a steady rotational speed (like mentioned in the comments). An increase of Amperage goes along with the design principles of synchronous machines/motors, but somehow the RPM decreases and that is the point i get confused with.

**Edit:** I am reading the amperage and voltage of the power generator, which i am using to supply the ESC and motor.
The things i know about the ESC - Motor system are:

- it's a synchronous machine
- User Manual: https://dl.djicdn.com/downloads/e800/en/E800_User_Manual_v1.0_en.pdf

I am grateful for any hint!

Cheers!

Comment: Please [edit] to hyperlink the datasheets from the part numbers. A schematic might be helpful too along with some details of your measurement technique.

Comment: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* - we do design here and analyse designs and you need to provide a lot more to get this answered. It boils down to the ESC algorithms and maybe nobody but the designers are privy to this. What you describe sounds reasonable to me. A small speed reduction with an increase in voltage to drive the same motor current. Not unreasonable.

Comment: How are you measuring voltage and amperage? Reduced speed implies increased torque load => increased current => increased power at the same voltage, contradicting your (unknown technique) measurements.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies. I am sorry to not fit in the electronic design frame perfectly, but this was the only place i thought i would get suitable answers.
I think, this reduction of RPM is actually a curcuit specific issue. Somehow - even though it is a synchronous machine - the rotational speed is reduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An increase of load (drag increase) should lead to a lagging of the
> rotor, which again **leads to an increase of amperage and finally to an**
> **increase of torque** and a syncing of the rotor, thus keeping a steady
> rotational speed (like mentioned in the comments). An increase of
> Amperage goes along with the design principles of synchronous
> machines/motors, **but somehow the RPM decreases** and that is the
> point i get confused with.

What you are missing is that the motor windings have resistance. When the current increases it creates higher voltage drop across the winding resistance, so the effective applied voltage is lower. The motor then spins slower because the back-emf (generated voltage) must match the applied voltage. The equivalent circuit of a PM DC motor makes this clear:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpmXrN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The controller syncs to whatever speed the motor runs at, so the 'lag' becomes a slower speed. Some controllers have a 'governor' mode which tries to maintain constant speed by increasing throttle (raising the external applied voltage) to compensate for voltage drop in the windings.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, i did not see this. This explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Following the edit : whew, it's just working as expected.
Increased load => increased torque demand => increased current at same voltage.

The ESC detects the rotor position (for sensorless, generally by sensing back EMF) and reduces the frequency to stay in sync with the motor.